# RxJava operator for cached item provider

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm trying to implement a provider that looks for items in `memory`, `disk`, `network`, in this order. The main purpose of this is to **avoid network calls** if I have the right local cache. There is a catch, since my calls to the network use filters to get items, I could have 10 items from the local query, but still need to go to the network because those items come from a different network call, with different query parameters.

Right now I'm using a `concat` with a `firstOrDefault`, checking that the list isn't null or empty. I've implemented a way to check if I already called the server with the specific query and I use it to return null when reading from disk.

I now need to refine the provider, so that it:

1. emits local items
2. go online **if needed**
3. emits online items

(Right now it stops at the first good list of items).

I'm trying with `takeWhile`, using a method that returns true if data is null or empty or if I didn't already call the server for that query. The problem is that takeWhile doesn't emit the item if the check for that item is false, meaning I won't get the last good item (which is also the best one).

The best solution I can think of is an operator that emits items until a certain condition comes up and then unsubscribe itself. I can't find one.

EDIT: SOME CODE
Solution 1) using `firstOrDefault`: will not emit local items if `!DiskService.wasDownloaded()`, because `DiskService` return a null `List<Item>` with `!DiskService.wasDownloaded()`

```
public Observable<List<Item>> items() {
    List<Observable> obs = new ArrayList<>();

    Observable<List<Item>> memoryObs = Observable.defer(this::getMemoryItems);

    Observable<List<Item>> diskObs = Observable.defer(this::getDiskItems);

    Observable<List<Item>> networkObs = Observable.defer(this::getNetworkItems);

    Observable<List<Item>> concat = Observable.concat(memoryObs, diskObs, networkObs;


    return concat.firstOrDefault(new ArrayList<>(), this::canAccept);
}

private boolean canAccept(List<Item> data) {
    return data != null && data.size() > 0;
}

//Method in DiskService
public boolean wasDownloaded(){
    return true if the query was performed on the server, false otherwise.
}
```

Solution 2) Using `takeWhile`. The problem with takeWhile is the Observable will not emit the item that doesn't check its condition, meaning I won't get the best List. The hacky solution is to defer the false check to the next item, but this way a network request will be fired even when not necessary. With this solution I'm using a `TrustedItemList` that just contains the List and a boolean that tells the Observable if he can trust a non-empty list of items (always true for `memory` and `network`, true if `wasDownloaded()` for `disk`)

```
public Observable<List<Item>> items() {
    List<Observable> obs = new ArrayList<>();

    Observable<TrustedItemList> memoryObs = Observable.defer(this::getMemoryItems);

    Observable<TrustedItemList> diskObs = Observable.defer(this::getDiskItems);

    Observable<TrustedItemList> networkObs = Observable.defer(this::getNetworkItems);

    Observable<TrustedItemList> concat = Observable.concat(memoryObs, diskObs, networkObs;


    return concat.takeWhile(this::shouldContinueSearching)
                 .filter(trustedItemList -> trustedItemList.items != null && !trustedItemList.items.isEmpty())
                 .map(trustedItemList -> trustedItemList.items);
}

private boolean shouldContinueSearching(TrustedPoiList data) {
     return data == null || data.items == null || data.items.isEmpty() || !data.canTrustIfNotEmpty; 
}
```

Comment: I would recommend adding a little code for us to get the context, because right now it looks somewhat abstract and favouring towards giving generic answers like using `combineLatest()`.

Comment: I've added some "pseudo" code (not that pseudo). The problem with combineLatest is that the network request will always fire, which is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using a custom `Observable.Operator`, shamelessly copied from `OperatorTakeWhile`, with the sole change of calling `subscriber.onNext(t)` just before `subscriber.onCompleted()` in the `onNext` method. This way the last item, the one that returns false on the boolean check, is emitted.

```
public final class OperatorTakeWhileWithLast<T> implements Observable.Operator<T, T> {

    private final Func2<? super T, ? super Integer, Boolean> predicate;

    public OperatorTakeWhileWithLast(final Func1<? super T, Boolean> underlying) {
        this((input, index) -> {
            return underlying.call(input);
        });
    }

    public OperatorTakeWhileWithLast(Func2<? super T, ? super Integer, Boolean> predicate) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    @Override
    public Subscriber<? super T> call(final Subscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
        Subscriber<T> s = new Subscriber<T>(subscriber, false) {
            private int counter = 0;
            private boolean done = false;

            @Override
            public void onNext(T t) {
                boolean isSelected;
                try {
                    isSelected = predicate.call(t, counter++);
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    done = true;
                    Exceptions.throwIfFatal(e);
                    subscriber.onError(OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(e, t));
                    unsubscribe();
                    return;
                }
                if (isSelected) {
                    subscriber.onNext(t);
                } else {
                    done = true;
                    subscriber.onNext(t); //Just added this line
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                    unsubscribe();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                if (!done) {
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                if (!done) {
                    subscriber.onError(e);
                }
            }
        };
        subscriber.add(s);
        return s;
    }
}
```

My `items()` method (solution 2) now ends with:

```
return concat.lift(new OperatorTakeWhileWithLast<TrustedItemList>(this::shouldContinueSearching))  
             .filter(trustedItemList -> trustedItemList.items != null && !trustedItemList.items.isEmpty()) 
             .map(trustedItemList -> trustedItemList.items);
```